# Why in Apache Spark Structured Streaming console sink does not work in update output mode

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I wrote very simple application that read stream of csv files does some aggregation and write the stream to console. This is the error it reports:

```
Data source v2 streaming sinks does not support Update mode
```

I did everything according to the book. Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the code that you have written?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. It would help a lot if you could share more information on your issue, such as what you've tried to fix your issue, relevant excerpts of your code or the language used since the spark engine is compatible with multiple languages.